# Paste Cell Reference from another worksheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to get this script to work but cannot work it out.

So i would like the result on Sheet 1 from Sheet 4.

```
function myFunction() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]; 
ss.getRange('AM2').activate();
ss.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=[4] AL3');
```

I hope i am close ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

- Firstly, define the sheets you want to work with:

  ```
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sheet4 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet4');
  ```
- Get the value of cell `AL3` in `Sheet4`:

  ```
  var value = sheet4.getRange('AL3').getValue();
  ```
- Set it to cell `AM2` in `Sheet1`:

  ```
  sheet1.getRange('AM2').setValue(value);
  ```

---

If you want to use the formula instead, then just do that:

```
var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
sheet1.getRange('AM2').setFormula('Sheet4!AL3');
```

### Solution:

I think you are looking for this:

```
function myFunction() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
var sheet4 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet4');
var value = sheet4.getRange('AL3').getValue();
// sheet1.getRange('AM2').setValue(value); // if you want the value use this
sheet1.getRange('AM2').setFormula('Sheet4!AL3'); // if you want the formula use this
}
```

If the name of the sheets have a space between the word and the number, for example `Sheet 1` instead of `Sheet1` and `Sheet 4` instead of `Sheet4`, then use this solution:

```
function myFunction() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet 1');
var sheet4 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet 4');
var value = sheet4.getRange('AL3').getValue();
//sheet1.getRange('AM2').setValue(value); // if you want the value use this
sheet1.getRange('AM2').setFormula("'Sheet 4'!AL3") // if you want the formula use this 
}
```